# Design process of directional coupler

Tags: optics

I know that when two wavegudies are brought sufficiently close enough, the electromagnetic fields overlap and light can be coupled from one waveguide to the other. However, how to calculate the coupling gap between the two waveguides? And, how to calculate the coupling length needed to achieve certain coupling efficiency? Are there any closed form solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are closed form solutions for very simple ideal cases such as two planar waveguides, having no bends, with step-index profiles, made of a uniform material, having no losses, ...

But real couplers have none of that.  The waveguides have to bend in order to bring the two waveguides near each other, leading to bending losses at the coupler.  The waveguides are not planar, so the fields generally cannot be calculated exactly.  The material is very often not homogeneous, containing perhaps multiple quantum wells, adding additional difficulties to the field calculation.

Practically speaking, in almost all cases numerical simulation is required to get reasonably accurate results.